# Cookies reappear after being deleted

Tags: asp.net, cookies

Here is my code for removing the cookie:

```
HttpCookie c1 = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["id"];
c1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
c1.Value = "0";
Response.Cookies.Add(c1);
var test = Request.Cookies["id"].Value; //Test to check if cookie was deleted or at least changed the value.
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
```

Now when i debug this and reach the var = test line of code the cookie value is equal to 0. which is good, but when i move to another page, suddenly all the changes have been revoked, the id cookie returns to its last value. I tried refreshing the page, but nothing works.
I just cant get rid of these cookies...

Comment: did any of this cookie manipulation get sent over to the client? remember, cookies are sent with EVERY request. if your headers with the delete instructions never get sent to the client, the client will not know the cookies should be deleted and just send them again with the next request, as it should.

Comment: @MarcB I don't know... How do i make sure they get sent to the client?